How to uninstall entirely SystemPackages in windows 11, like "Microsoft.PeoplesHost" or "Microsoft.BioEnrollment" and so on
Title.
I would like to uninstall completely a certain number of system-packages which are marked as "NonRemovable" as mentioned in the title. Want just to debloat windows 11 to the fullest.
I currently use PowerShell with this command but it does not work.
Get-AppxPackage -allUsers *Xbox* | Remove-AppxPackage -allUsers

I get this errorlog:

Remove-AppxPackage : The request is not supported.
Error 0x80070032: AppX Deployment operation Remove for the package
"Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI_1000.22621.1.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy" from
"C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI_cw5n1h2txyewy" has failed. This app is part of
Windows and cannot be uninstalled on a user basis. An administrator can try to enable or disable the app using
"Enable or disable Windows features" to remove the app from the computer. However, it may not be possible to
be uninstalled

For any tipps and useable suggestions i am already very thankful!
